# Can Not Re-Initialize FileOutputStream in Try-Resource JAVA SE7

Tags: java, intellij-idea

As you know JAVA SE7 has bringed try-resource feature and i have tried to implement in my application.

Here is a problem:

```
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path)){

//........ some code

fos = new FileOutputStream(newPath); // Getting Error!

}
```

My ide(IntelliJ IDEA) gives me this error " can not initialize final variable fos"

If i dont use try resource feature there is no problem so what should i do to reinitalize fos with try resource?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty straightforward: **final variable**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, because this syntactic sugar also declares the resource references as final. It makes sense, since the whole point is that the reference will be closed at the end of the block. If you were free to lose the reference in the block, would it be of much use?

Meaning, there is almost surely a different and better way to express what you are trying to. Perhaps you are looping over resources that you open. Each should be opened and closed. You can do *that* within an inner try-catch.